# How to create struct which is composed of another

Tags: go

I have a struct like so:

```
type Docs struct {
    Methods []string
    Route string
}
```

and then I import that from another file like:

```
import tc "huru/type-creator"
```

and use it like so:

```
type DocsLocal struct {
    tc.Docs
}
```

I am pretty certain that tc.Docs is just a field in DocsLocal, so this would be a case of composition, right?

if I want to create new instance of DocsLocal, I try this:

```
d:= DocsLocal{}
```

but how do I pass in the Methods and Route parameters? If I do this:

```
methods:= []string{"foo"}
r:="biscuit"
d:= DocsLocal{methods, r}
```

I get an error:

> Cannot use methods (type []string) as type tc.Docs more

So what is the right syntax to use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
d := DocsLocal{tc.Docs{[]string{"foo"}, "biscuit"}}
```

or

```
d := DocsLocal{Docs: tc.Docs{[]string{"foo"}, "biscuit"}}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/b7gjx64waJP)